# How to demarshall an object from a Xamarin.Android application in an Android Studio application?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to send an object created in Xamarin to my application created in Android Studio. However, I am running into the issue of ClassLoader Not Found. The ClassLoader is definitely being sent with the object(I use bundle.SetClassLoader(MyObject.Class.ClassLoader). I think the issue stems from the fact that the classes are different in each platform because one is written in Java while the other in C#. How do I ensure that the classes are the same despite the language differences?

Here is the Java Class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
public class Person implements Parcelable {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest,int flags)
{
    dest.writeString(firstName);
    dest.writeString(lastName);
    dest.writeInt(age);
}
public String getName()
{
    return firstName +" " + lastName;
}
public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator(){
    public Person createFromParcel(Parcel in){
        return new Person(in);
    }
    public Person[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Person[size];
    }
};
public Person(Parcel in)
{
    firstName = in.readString();
    lastName = in.readString();
    age = in.readInt();
}
```

}
and here is the C# class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Interop;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace Greetings.Droid
{
    public class Person : Object,IParcelable 
{
    [ExportField("Creator")]
    public static CREATOR InitializeCreator()
    {
        return new CREATOR();
    }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteString(firstName);
        dest.WriteString(lastName);
        dest.WriteInt(age);
    }
    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

}


public class CREATOR: Object,IParcelableCreator
{
    public Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        return new Person(source.ReadString(),   source.ReadString(),source.ReadInt());

    }
    public Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        return new Object[size];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin use Register to set explicit name of parcelable class

```
[Register("com.google.xxx.yyy.MyParcelableClass")]
class MyParcelableClass: Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
...
}
```

in java use corresponding package

```
package com.google.xxx.yyy.MyParcelableClass;
public class MyParcelableClassimplements Parcelable
{
   ...
}
```

and make sure that in proguard rules you have

```
-dontobfuscate
```